# How can i get rid of the flickering in my controls

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, draw

Im using MFC dialog based program have an activex explorer and 2 edit box.
On OnPaint() i draw the background image with BitBlt like this:

```
CDC mTempDC;
CBitmap mBitmap;
mTempDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
mBitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, m_BMBackgroundSize.cx, m_BMBackgroundSize.cy);
mTempDC.SelectObject(&mBitmap);

// Background
{
    CDC dcMemory;
    dcMemory.CreateCompatibleDC(&mTempDC);
    dcMemory.SelectObject(&m_BMBackground);
    mTempDC.BitBlt(0,0,m_BMBackgroundSize.cx,m_BMBackgroundSize.cy,&dcMemory,0,0,SRCCOPY);
    dcMemory.DeleteDC();
}

dc.BitBlt(0,0,m_BMBackgroundSize.cx, m_BMBackgroundSize.cy,&mTempDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
mTempDC.DeleteDC();
```

in OnMouseMove() i check if the mouse is in a certain area and if yes i call Invalidate(1) and the program start flickering everytime i move the mouse in that certain area.
I did try the OnEraseBkgnd return TRUE with no luck.
The only work around ive found is to manually redraw the edit box myself like this:

```
pCtrl = GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
pCtrlDC = pCtrl->GetDC();
mTempDC.BitBlt(5, 31, 580, 183, pCtrlDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

I am not sure if this the good way of doing it but it works and i did tons of research and testing with google for 5 hours long with no luck :\

Comment: To get rid of flickering, you usually have to draw in memory device context first.

Comment: Oh, the lost art of double buffering... (a good google term, though).

Comment: I guess none of you read the code, i AM using a second buffer to draw all my stuffs onto it and ONLY then i draw that buffer on the DC.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invalidating the entire window with `Invalidate`, just invalidate the part that needs to change with `InvalidateRect`.

The flickering is occurring because the edit controls are being erased and redrawn when you draw the background. If they're outside of the invalid rectangle this won't happen.

Comment: I managed to stop the flickering by drawing each control manually in OnPaint(), is it ok ?

Comment: @user1588293 there's nothing wrong with it except that it's redundant, the controls are now getting painted twice at each invalidation.